# Waveshare Jetbot not Powering up

Tags: hardware, nvidia-jetson

I have been trying to build a Jetson Nano powered Jetbot using the hardware supplied by WaveShare. I assembled the hardware by following the instructions [here](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/JetBot_AI_Kit_Assemble_Manual). But unfortunately, it doesn't power up when I turn it on. I have checked my Jetson Nano separately and it works fine. Even the batteries are charged and shows about 4.2V when checked with a multimeter. Does anyone have any idea about what might be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jetbot board has to be connected to the power adapter for a while to enable the power of the batteries (even when the batteries are fully charged). This step has to be done only once but is an indispensable step to allow the jetson nano to draw power from the batteries. Apparently, it has not been mentioned in the instructions on the WaveShare website.

Comment: After powering it for 15 minutes, I can turn my Jetbot on. Then plug off the power cord and the car still has power. Able to run "Basic Movement" in Python Jupyter. But immediately after just able to make the car turn Left, the car turns off. Then I plug in the power cord back again and leave it overnight in hopes of charging the battery back again. The car won't turn on anymore! (Jetson is still functional by plugging in USB.)

Answer (score 0):

check the multicolored cable that connects the Waveshare expansion board and battery holder to the Jetson Nano.  Make sure it has the proper orientation when plugged into each board.  It is part number 15 in the WaveShare JetBot AI Kit Assembly manual.

Comment: I followed this step correctly. The problem was that there is a protective circuit onboard that apparently keeps the power from batteries disabled somehow until the jetbot is connected to the power adapter for a while.